# socket doesn't close when thread done

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I have a problem with sockets. This:

[image]

When client-thread ends, server trying to read, and its freezes, because socket is not closed. Thread dont close it, when its over. Its problem exist, if i using thread, but if i using two independents projects, i have no problem (exception throws, and i can catch it). 
I cant use timeout, and i must correct continue server-work, when client dont close socket.
Sorry for my bad eng.

Comment: .NET isn't magic. The socket won't close unless you _tell_ it to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way for TCP server (listener) to find out whether data from client are not coming because it has died/quit or is just inactive. This is not .NET's defficiency, it is how TCP works. The way I deal with it is:
1. Create a timer in my client that periodically sends signal "I am alive" to the server. For example, I just send 1 unusual ASCII character '∩' (code 239).
2. In TCP listener: use `NetworkStream.Read(...)` method that allows to specify timeout. If timeout expires, the server disposes the old NetworkStream instance and creates new one on the same TCP port. If the server receives "I am alive" signal from client, it keeps listening.

By the way, the property `TcpClient.Connected` is useless for detecting on server side whether client still uses the socket. The method only returns `true` if last Read action returned something. So, if client is alive and just silent, the `TcpClient.Connected` becomes false.

Answer (score 2):

Close `client` when you want the connection to be closed (at the end of `Client`).

Better yet, use `using` for all disposable resources such as both clients and the listener.

Comment: it is a problem -- i need to insure my server. any client should not be able to down server.